Jackson: cannot deserialize polymorphic object in submodule
I need to deserialize a json into an object of a child class. The json is deserialized using DebeziumSerdes, which in turn uses jackson at its core. However, I'm met with the exception:
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'childClass' as a subtype of `AggregateRoot`: known type ids = [aggregateRoot]

My project structure and code implementation is as follow:
common module:

AggregateRoot class:

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type",
)
@JsonTypeName("aggregateRoot")
@Getter
public class AggregateRoot {
    protected final String id;

    protected AggregateRoot() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}

submodule module:

build.gradle.kts:

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common"))
}


ChildClass:

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@JsonTypeName("childClass")
public class ChildClass extends AggregateRoot {
    private String name;
}


KafkaConfig class:

@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AggregateRoot> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        Serde<AggregateRoot> valueSerde = DebeziumSerdes.payloadJson(AggregateRoot.class);
        valueSerde.configure(props, false);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), valueSerde.deserializer());
    }
}

I have been avoiding using @JsonSubTypes because it will introduce cyclic dependency. I would also like to be able to add new type of child without having to modify the base class.
I have tried following answers from various similar questions, but none made it work. Most questions don't mention having submodules, so I suspect it might be related to the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
Among the answers, there are suggestions to use JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS instead, and it works, but having the full path of the class messes with the process to maintain data consistency between microservices, so I'd rather not having to use it.
I have also tried modifying the deserializer to use ChildClass instead of AggregateRoot, and it works, but it removes the polymorphism, which means I will have to add more deserializers if I have a SecondChildClass and implement a deserializer chooser, which is probably bad practice.
